# What is the difference between crude oil futures and CFDs?

Tags: commodities, cfd, crude-oil

In April 2020 WTI crude oil futures price gone negative.

I trade crude oil CFDs using **eToro** and **IqOption**. On these platforms oil prices were different. On eToro the lowest price was around 7.3 while on IqOption it was around 8.4.

There's yet another picture on TradingView symbols:

- `USOIL` and `USDWTI` were at 0
- `OIL_CRUDE` was at 9.8

Who can I trust? How CFD brokers get their prices? Can oil CFD go negative?

Comment: There are different oil futures (Brent is the most common) - aare you sure you were trading WTI CFDs?

Comment: @DStanley, Yes, on IqOption they call it USOUSD. When I asked them what's the difference, they answered something vague like "go read the specs about this commodity on our website". I'm wondering whether they set those prices themselves to overplay us.

Comment: USO is different. It is a trust (company) that buys and sell oil futures.

Comment: @DStanley, I know that. But it seems USOUSD is not USO. On both eToro and IqOption USO is quoted at 20, but USOUSD at 26.

Comment: Then I agree with their suggestion - go read the specs to know what you're trading.

Comment: @DStanley, There is not much info: https://tr-iqoption.com/en/commodities/USOUSD